# Getting client ip address in flask

Tags: http-headers, ip, client-server, flask

I am trying to get the client ip at the server Y in the following scenario,

client requests server X which forwards the request to server Y.

And the return flow is Y->X->client

'REMOTE_ADDR' in the http header(actually i get it from request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']) has the ip of server X. From where can i get the ip of the client at server Y ?

**UPDATE:**

X has a public ip. Y is in a private network and is inaccessible outside. Now i am using a client in the same private network and i request X via the public network.

I just want to know if the header already has what i need without manipulating the header at X to include ip of client.

Comment: Do you run Flask's appserver behind a proxy? In this case it's obvious that the client is actually the proxy.

Comment: Are you running your app with ``app.run``? (You should use that one only in development btw)

Comment: ya i am doing that. i am still developing. But what does that have to do with this:

Comment: Is server X sending requests to server Y?

Answer (score 2):

If your application is behind a proxy then the remote address of the request will appear to your application to be from the proxy, not the actual client.

There is no provision in the http spec to pass on the 'real' address but the de-facto standard for doing this is by having your proxy set an [X-Forwarded-For header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Werkzeug provides a [fixer](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix) to help with this, and there's an example detailed in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups), `request.remote_addr` should then be what you expect

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. basically X is not a proxy. It is a server that, based on the incoming requests finds a server to request(one of it is Y) and sends the response to the client.

Comment: X-FORWARDED-For is not found in the header at Y. "I added           from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)". request.remote_addr gives the same, ie the ip of server X at server Y. I just want to know if the header already has what i need without manipulating the header.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your claims, X is basically a proxy, since it makes its own request to Y, based on a request the user makes. So it's perfectly valid that `REMOTE_ADDR` is the one of X.

You will have to add a custom header to X's requests, like `X-Original-User-IP` to make the user's IP available to Y. You can use `ProxyFix` for this if you want, it will rewrite `X-Forwarded-For` to `REMOTE_ADDR`

**You should make sure Y is only available to X and cannot be accessed directly. Otherwise one could spoof his IP address simply by sending that custom header.**

Comment: In fact you need to make sure Y is only available to X *and* that Y *removes* any existing X-Forwarded-For headers from the client. The default for most proxies is to append to that header and ProxyFix selects the first one, so unless you're really careful you can easily open yourself up to IP spoofing. See http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html